# How do I set Windows Explorer in Windows 7 to display metadata / tags of Ogg Vorbis (.OGG) files when in 'Details' view?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, tags, ogg

How do I set Windows Explorer in Windows 7 to display metadata / tags (Artist, Song Title, etc.) of Ogg Vorbis (.OGG) files when in 'Details' view?

Comment: Related question 2 years later: http://superuser.com/questions/472723/free-tool-to-display-audio-ogg-properties-in-windows-7-explorer

Comment: @rjnagle That question is a possible duplicate of this one. See [my comment on this answer to my question](http://superuser.com/a/214716/10259) (or my edit to that answer, if it has been approved).

Comment: I didn't probe deeply enough to realize you were the OP on the question.  I thought you were loading up the answer with info on a product you were affiliated with.  I still think the comparison info link is a bit advertisement like, but if you want to put it through again, I'll approve it.  Please accept my apologies.

Comment: @jonsca I put that edit to AdamKessel's answer to help others, like rjnagle, who are [looking for a freeware solution](http://superuser.com/questions/472723/free-tool-to-display-audio-ogg-properties-in-windows-7-explorer). That edit is mainly to provide info and links to show that there is a freeware version, hence the comparison info. Is it possible to "un-reject" [that edit suggestion of mine](http://superuser.com/review-beta/suggested-edits/28555)?

Comment: @galacticninja I have no way to unreject it, regrettably.  I will try flagging the answer, but I don't think a mod would be able to reverse it either.

Comment: @galacticninja Oliver incorporated the information, but if you want to submit another edit, someone can put it through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[dBpoweramp Music Converter](http://www.dbpoweramp.com/dmc.htm) with the [OGG decoder](http://www.dbpoweramp.com/codec-central.htm) installed fixes this problem. It is freeware.

Please note that the file download in the [link above](http://www.dbpoweramp.com/dmc.htm) is the trial version of the dBpoweramp 'Reference' version. It converts to dBpoweramp 'Free' after 21 days. The free version still has the metadata display feature in the 'Details' view.

[Comparison between dBpoweramp Free and Reference](http://www.dbpoweramp.com/db-versions.htm)

[Alternative download link](http://www.filehippo.com/download_dbpoweramp_music_converter/)

Comment: dBpoweramp Music Converter download link: http://www.dbpoweramp.com/dmc.htm   Please note that the file download in the [link above](http://www.dbpoweramp.com/dmc.htm) is the trial version of the dBpoweramp 'Reference' version. It converts to dBpoweramp 'Free' after 21 days. The free version still has the metadata display feature in the 'Details' view. [Comparison between dBpoweramp Free and Reference](http://www.dbpoweramp.com/db-versions.htm)

Answer (score 1):

There is a more simple way now, using the property handler for ogg files:

[Taglib Property Handler](http://sourceforge.net/projects/taglibhandler/) (open source)

[image]

TLPH is based on [TagLib Audio Meta-Data Library](http://taglib.github.io/). About the latter:

> Currently it supports both ID3v1 and ID3v2 for MP3 files, Ogg Vorbis
>   comments and ID3 tags and Vorbis comments in FLAC, MPC, Speex, WavPack
>   TrueAudio, WAV, AIFF, MP4 and ASF files.

Answer (score 1):

[AudioShell](http://www.softpointer.com/AudioShell.htm) is a free shell extension for OGG and also includes other formats like Opus, FLAC and APE tags.