# Free tool to display audio ogg properties in Windows 7 Explorer?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, ogg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set Windows Explorer in Windows 7 to display metadata / tags of Ogg Vorbis (.OGG) files when in 'Details' view?](https://superuser.com/questions/195066/how-do-i-set-windows-explorer-in-windows-7-to-display-metadata-tags-of-ogg-vor)

Windows Explorer Vista/7 does not show ogg metadata properties in Windows Explorer

On another question I see that someone recommended dbPowerAmp Music Converter.
[How do I set Windows Explorer in Windows 7 to display metadata / tags of Ogg Vorbis (.OGG) files when in 'Details' view?](https://superuser.com/questions/195066/how-do-i-set-windows-explorer-in-windows-7-to-display-metadata-tags-of-ogg-vor)

I have not tried that tool, but even if it works, it is a commercial tool costing $38.

I also see some shell extensions exist for Win XP/2000 like Audio Shell http://www.softpointer.com/AudioShell.htm, but these may not work in Vista/7 64 bit.

I also see that there is a property handler for flac files on Win 7 http://www.sevenforums.com/music-pictures-video/174276-windows-cant-read-flac-tags-2.html#post1531805

Comment: The [dBpoweramp Music Converter download link](http://www.dbpoweramp.com/dmc.htm), in its official page, is described to be a download of the trial version of the dBpoweramp 'Reference' version. It converts to dBpoweramp 'Free' after 21 days. The free version still has the metadata display feature in Windows Explorer. [Comparison between dBpoweramp Free and Reference](http://www.dbpoweramp.com/db-versions.htm)

Comment: See my answer for this question: [How do I set Windows Explorer in Windows 7 to display metadata / tags of Ogg Vorbis (.OGG) files when in 'Details' view?](http://superuser.com/questions/195066/how-do-i-set-windows-explorer-in-windows-7-to-display-metadata-tags-of-ogg-vor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the free version of dbPowrAmp (which reads OGG in the details column in W7) at http://www.filehippo.com/download_dbpoweramp_music_converter/

Comment: Thanks, that is awesome information! I was thinking of trying the commercial version of dbPowerAmp, but it's good to know there's a free version as well.